# change strength of antialiasing in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, antialiasing

Is it possible to increase the antialiasing in matplotlib?
I can still see some aliasing in my data, I tried several backends and it is still there. The antialiasing flag of the lines is set.

Here you can see what I mean

[image]

It's a sample taken from a Screenshot. It's probably not the best example but I guess one can see the stairs in the line. It was taken with the wxagg backend.

I'm using matplotlib version 1.01 with Windows 7.

Update:
I don't have the code which produced the previous picture anymore, but I still have the problem. Below is a simple code example which shows the aliasing.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('wxAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
print 'Backend:', pl.get_backend()

x = np.linspace(0,6,100)
y = np.sin(x)

for a in range(10):
    pl.plot( x, a/10.*x, linewidth=1)

pl.show()
```

It print's `Backend: WXAgg`
And the resulting plot looks like the following.
[image: aliasing]

Especially the lower red curve shows clear aliasing.

Comment: render your plot at higher pixel dimensions and down scale with a high quality algorithm.

Comment: but what about interactive sessions?

Comment: Are you referring to image plots with `imshow`?  If so, that has nothing to do with antialiasing, that's just the interpolation algorithm used by `imshow`.  (It interpolates the 3-band color array, rather than the original data, which can lead to a lot of artifacts.)

Comment: no I'm refering to simple line plots.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was jumping to conclusions... What backend are you using?  Some backends handle it better than others.  The Agg-based backends antialiasing well. Some of the others don't.

Comment: Check with `plt.get_backend()`

Comment: This might honestly be the best you can do. Do you have any examples of single-pixel anti-aliased lines which look better?

Comment: @MarkRansom A plot stored as pdf for example shows a lot less aliasing(at the same size).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The picture you added to your question is already perfectly anti-aliased. It doesn't get any better than this. Have a look at a zoomed version of the image:

[image: Upscaled version of the image in question]

Comment: You're correct that this is well anti-aliased, but I'm not sure I would go so far as "perfect". There's a lot of factors that go into a good anti-alias algorithm.

Comment: 1. It doesn't seem to have limited number of shades (likes Windows Font rendering for example)
2. No visible artifacts.
3. Subpixel rendering is not an option for red things.
4. The width of a pixel-span in each row is defined by the line width, so can't be changed by the algorithm.

I really don't know how this could be improved in any way. Do you see a way?

Comment: I wasn't even referring to subpixel rendering. You've brought up one factor, the number of shades, which is determined by the amount of supersampling applied. I can think of others: shape and size of the filter, linearity of the color space.

Comment: True, you're right. Didn't think about gamma correction and those things. I tried several variations just now with Gamma correction and other scalings and couldn't make it look any better, without changing the line width. Would be interested to hear what you would change.

Comment: I think it's essential to do the filtering in a linear color space then gamma correct or convert to sRGB for the output. The filter choice will affect the tradeoff between blurriness and visibility of the steps. I was hoping to explore some of those choices myself, but I ran out of time and motivation.

Answer (score 6):

If you save the picture as a .svg file, you will have infinite precision. You can then edit this .svg with something like InkScape, and get how much precision/antialiasing as you like.

Comment: Yeah, export to `svg -> inkscape -> export to png at 5x the dpi -> GIMP -> [blur slightly? ->] scale to 20% -> export to png again`. Totally removed the white lines between neighbouring polygons for me.